# SQL: In UNION vs UNION ALL, what is the implied ID?

Tags: sql

UNION Vs UNION ALL How does SQL know what to "join on". I realize that this is NOT a join, but there is an ID right for UNION and UNION ALL? Is it the first SELECT item?

That is, if in a UNION query, the overlapped records are not repeated, how does SQL identify the records to leave out?

Comment: It compares every column value from every row.

Comment: It is just the same result as doing a `UNION ALL` then a `DISTINCT` on that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "join" with a union.  Nor is there a concept of an "id".

The difference between `union` and `union all` is that `union` returns only unique records -- removing duplicates.  *All* columns that participate in the `union` are considered as one unit (you may say that all the columns are "keys").  And, for the purposes of uniqueness, `NULL` values are considered the same.

Comment: Ok so to see if I understand, If List A: Sally(20), Tom(21), Jim, Mark(22); List B: Sally(20), JOEY(30) , Tom(21) - UNION would include all of the people and their ages, while UNION ALL, would include all of the poeple and their ages, the difference being that Sally and Tom would appear twice?

Comment: @PortMadeleineCrumpet . . . I think you understand.